# Can't called component again after loop, show error "invariant Violation: Invalid tag"

Tags: reactjs, components

I create the component that passing via props on parent component, and use component inside map loop, but if I called it again after loop it show error `Invariant Violation: Invalid tag:`

`{ PropsPassedComponent: propsPassedComponent } = this.props`

```
<Wrapper>
 {dataList.map((data) => (
  <PropsPassedComponent data={data} key={data.id}>
 ))}
 <PropsPassedComponent last={true} key={dataList.length}> {/* <-- if I called Component agian here, it's show error */}
</Wrapper>
```

thankyou for consideration, tell me if you need more info.

Comment: I called <PropsPassedComponent> Component again after loop on line 5 in example code.

Comment: you forgot to close the component inside Loop: `<PropsPassedComponent data={data} key={data.id}/>` close that.

Comment: oh sorry,  I forgot it on code example, but in my real code is already close it.

Comment: can you show the full error message?

Comment: it's show `Invariant Violation: Invalid tag` ...